# Why are VBox children not displaying when added dynamically?

Tags: java, javafx, vbox

Could anyone please explain why this is not working?

Loop (should) create a repeating pattern of `VBox`'s inside a `VBox`, inside a `ScrollPane`, inside a `BorderPane` (central position), each with different data drawn from a database.

```
    public void equipmentPaneBuilder(LinkedList<ModelEquipment> list) {
        LinkedList<ModelEquipment> equipmentList = list;

        for (int i = 0; i < equipmentList.size(); i++) {
            ModelEquipment item = equipmentList.get(i);

            try {
                PaneEquipment equipmentPane = new PaneEquipment();
                equipmentPane.updateFields(item.getTechId(), item.getShortName(), item.getLongDesc()); equipmentPane.setId("equipPane" + i);

                EquipmentPanels.getChildren().add(equipmentPane);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the custom node built on `VBox` that should be added to the `EquipmentPanels` VBox using the method above.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class PaneEquipment extends VBox {

    @FXML   private TextField techId;
    @FXML   private TextField shortText;
    @FXML   private TextArea longDesc;


    public PaneEquipment() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/PaneEquipment.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }


    public void updateFields(String techIdArg, String shortNameArg, String longDescArg) {

        techID.setText(techIdArg);
        shortText.setText(shortNameArg);
        longDesc.setText(longDescArg);

    }

}
```

FXML for the `PaneEquipment` objects/nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="Tech ID" />
            <TextField fx:id="techID" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Tech ID Number" />
            <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Name" />
            <TextField fx:id="shortText" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="465.0" promptText="Short text description (max. 40 characters)" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="132.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Description" wrapText="true" />
            <TextArea fx:id="longDesc" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="682.0" promptText="Long text description (max. 300 characters)" wrapText="true" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Based on my testing, everything is working fine, except that the `equipmentPane`'s are not displaying when the program runs, I just get a blank scroll pane.  The database and linked list work fine.  The updatefields method works fine.  No exception is printed.

If I replace the `equipmentPaneBuiler` loop with this, it displays correctly:

```
try {
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    Label label = new Label();
    vbox.getChildren().add("text");
    EquipmentPanels.getChildren().add(vbox);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So I presume it's an issue with my custom node, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: [mcve] ... and java naming conventions please

Comment: Honestly I try to get that right, but still get called out on it.  Could you please give a specific example, because I keep thinking it’s right and apparently am way off.

Comment: field names must start with lower-case

Comment: @kleopatra OK thanks, I thought it was different for javafx fields for some reason.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Here's a list of Java naming conventions: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming

Comment: @Slaw bookmarked, cheers.  I've only been writing code for a few months, self-taught, there is a lot to take in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not implement the *Custom Component* approach 100% correctly.

In your case 2 distinct `VBox`es (or `VBox`-derived objects) exist during the execution of the `PaneEquipment` constructor. The object being constructed and the `VBox` created by `FXMLLoader`. The `VBox` created by `FXMLLoader` contains the contents but gets ignored and you only add the empty `PaneEquipment`.

To implement the approach correctly you need to use `PaneEquipment` as root and replace the root element of the fxml with `<fx:root>`

```xml
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="Tech ID" />
            <TextField fx:id="TechID" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Tech ID Number" />
            <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="92.0" text="Name" />
            <TextField fx:id="ShortText" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="465.0" promptText="Short text description (max. 40 characters)" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="132.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Description" wrapText="true" />
            <TextArea fx:id="LongDesc" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="682.0" promptText="Long text description (max. 300 characters)" wrapText="true" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

```
public PaneEquipment() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/PaneEquipment.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this); // add this line

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I knew it would be something little like that!  Thanks :D